# WP Catachable fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting the following error on my site, but only on the live version. The local version is just fine. PHP versions are the same, but is there a particular module in the php.ini file that should be turned on? I'm not sure where to look to fix this problem.

> **Catchable fatal error**:  Object of class WP_Error could not be
>   converted to string in
>   **/var/www/vhosts/qhxh-vznq.accessdomain.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/digiday-careers/content-single-job.php**
>   on line **184**

Below is where the error is occurring:

```
 <?php if (!empty($categories)) : ?>
    <div class="job-sidebar-info-block industry">
        <div class="title">Industry</div>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
            <?php if (class_exists('WP_Job_Manager_Cat_Colors')) : ?>
                <p>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($category, 'job_listing_category'); ?>" class="job-category <?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?>
                    </a>
                </p>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($category, 'job_listing_category'); ?>">
                        <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                        <?php echo $category->name; ?>
                    </a>
                </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: post the `content-single-job.php` code please

Comment: probably have something like `echo $object_without_magic_toString_method`.

Comment: may be you have to use is_wp_error()

Comment: which is the " line 184 " please mention or add full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the above code you mentioned with this code

```
<?php if(!empty($categories)):?>
    <div class="job-sidebar-info-block industry">
        <div class="title">Industry</div>
        <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) : ?>
            <?php if ( class_exists( 'WP_Job_Manager_Cat_Colors' ) ) : ?>
                <p><a href="<?php echo is_wp_error( get_term_link( $category, 'job_listing_category' )); ?>" class="job-category <?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></p>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p><a href="<?php echo is_wp_error(get_term_link( $category, 'job_listing_category' )); ?>"><i class="icon-book-open"></i> <?php echo $category->name; ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
 <?php endif;?>
```